Help in Solving a non-linear elliptic PDE
I am trying to solve the following PDE numerically, but I am unsure of what algorithm I should use to do so. The following snippet shows what I am working on:

There is also a periodic BC in $\theta$ where the solution in equal for $\theta=0$ and $\theta=2\pi$ for all $t$.
I just want some help/advice on what to use here! I am having trouble finding a canned routine to implement... I was thinking of relaxation, but everything I find is 1st order PDE or an ODE. Can anyone give me some advice on what canned routine might work here?

it is nonlinear, numerically you need to cook up an iterative way. For instance, $\Delta_{t,\theta} \alpha_n = f(\alpha_{n-1})$. Software like MATLAB should have a builtin tool to solve the Laplace equation.

Matlabs $\texttt{pdepe}$ can do this I guess. But I guess it is a dream to get the entire time horizon $(-\infty, \infty)$

And can you explain what $\delta_0 \Delta_0$ is?

Ok $\texttt{pdepe}$ is rather unlikely to work....

And what is $\varphi$?

For such an odd problem I doubt that such a nice canned routine is available. Elliptic evolution equations are not common. If $\theta$ is an angle such that it has compact support, then you could do a Fourier decomposition and reduce to some ODEs after truncation

Forgot to say that $\varphi$ is a constant and  same with the deltas (those being small constants). I am most used to matlab, but the canned routines are expensive and I do not have $$$600 to drop. I also forgot to say you can work on an interval $t\in[-10,2]$ or so. Not quite $\pm\infty$ but it works
